# Simplified function to create bound parameters

Tags: php

I'm trying to simplify binding parameters for queries that I am required to build. As these queries could contain up to 30 columns, I'd like a neat way to generate the placeholders for the query and assign them as such.

```
function get_placeholder_array($array) {
    $return = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $return[$item] = ":$item";
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Which does as required, generating an array for an insert query that looks like:

```
Array (
    [a] => :a
    [b] => :b
    ...etc
)
```

Now my issue lays here, how would I generate the actual binds being passed through from the user input, provided that they had the same names as the columns (<sup>*I know, bad practice, unfortunately I didn't write up this spec and can't deviate from the outline.*</sup>).

So if I had user inputted data as such:

```
$data = array(
    'a' => 'Some user input',
    'b' => 'Some other boring user input',
);
```

I'm looking for a simplified version, cause I could create a simple function like this to achieve it but am looking for something "sleeker":

```
function make_bind_array($keys, $data) {
    $response = array();
    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $response[":{$key}"] = $data[$key];
    }
    // return
    return $response;
}
```

So is there a simplified way of doing the above or do I just go with that?

---

#### Clarification

I'm doing this to minimize the amount of "garbage" code that I would have to write, so essentially taking a function that looks like this:

```
function doing_stuff($data) {
    $sql = $this->db->insert(
        'a' => ':a',
        'b' => ':b',
        'c' => ':c',
        'd' => ':d',
        'e' => ':e',
        'f' => ':f',
        'g' => ':g',
        'h' => ':h',
        'i' => ':i',
        'j' => ':j',
        'k' => ':k',
        'l' => ':l',
       ....etc
    , 'table');

   // create bind array and assign all a,b,c,d,e.... with the data element...
}
```

**I want it to assign the user input (i.e `$POST`) to the placeholders**

To something like this:

```
function doing_stuff($data) {
    $sql = $this->db->insert(get_placeholder_array($this->columns), 'table');
    $this->db->query($sql, make_bind_array($this->columns, $data));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not getting wrong you need an array with its value preceding with ":" right?

```
$array = array('a' => 'a', 'b' => 'b', 'c' => 'c', 'd' => 'd');
function formatting(&$arr, $key) {
    global $array;
    $array[$key] = ":$arr";
}
array_walk($array, 'formatting');
print_r($array);
```

Comment: What I'm looking for is the binding of the actual user input, so take `$_POST` for example

Comment: consider `$_POST` instead `$array`